# Detect both images using cv2 template matching

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have two images, I'm currently using the first one for template matching. It doesn't match all templates, maybe because in some templates cards are present, in some they are not. How can I use 1 template and match both cases ?

Image I'm using:

[image: Image I'm using]

The other image:

[image: The other image]

This the an example of input image from which I want to detect this template:

Example:

[image: Example]

I don't know much about template matching I am using TM_CCOEFF_NORMED

```
    match = cv2.matchTemplate(roi, resized_template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    
    rows, cols = np.where(match > match_threshold)
    values = match[rows, cols]
    
    for detect_x, detect_y, value in zip(cols, rows, values):
        detections += [(detect_x + roi_x, detect_y + roi_y, template_width, template_height, value)]
```

When I try matching the template using the first template example and filter by match threshold above 55%, it only matches the first two templates that have cards. When I use the second image as a template example it only matches the last one. I can use both but it slows down the process so I want to know if there's way to ignore the cards while matching but include them in the result. Maybe an image preprocessing method which ignores the cards. I might not even be the cards but I'm guessing it's the cards that are not letting it match.

Comment: everyone's following bad tutorials. don't ever use CCOEFF-anything. use SQDIFF. and please tell me _what tutorial_ you've been following so I can talk to the author and make them fix that.

Comment: TM_CCORR_NORMED (normalized cross correlation) should be OK as well as TM_SQDIFF, but not TM_CCOEFF_NORMED.

Comment: CCORR _also_ just multiplies. any modes that don't use differences are doomed. the only difference between CCORR and CCOEFF is that the latter subtracts the mean... which is somewhat better, but still garbage. all the NORMED stuff doesn't affect the mapping (and quality), only the scale of values. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d yes, those expressions take effort to decipher. they should just introduce some abstraction in these terms.